# Space in StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I'm looking to add a comma and one 'space' after a binding. I have the comma after the binding but I cannot work out at all how to do a 'space'. This is what I have;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}{0:\,}\,}" />
```

Could someone please inform me on how to add a 'space' after the comma? I have tried literally adding a space in the XAML but this does not work.

Answer (score 22):

XAML trims the string of whitespace unless you tell it where the string ends. Surround your string with single quotes.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0}\, '}" />
```

Comment: Perfect answer, see also: [How to format text using XAML StringFormat](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a100ee6-6206-422b-9b94-11760d325949/how-to-format-text-using-xaml-stringformat?forum=wpdevelop) for other uses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0},\&#x20;'}" />
```

with this you can also add CR and LF (\&#x10; \&#x13;).