# StringFormat with whitespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something}"/>` and I would like `Something` to be preceeded and succeeded by a space, effectively resulting in:

`(Something)`

instead of

`(Something)`

I've tried:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something, StringFormat={} {0} }"/>` but that results in  `(Something)` (i.e., space missing to the right)

I've also tried `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something, StringFormat=\ {0}\ }"/>` and although that *looks* properly in design mode, it won't compile (The text '\ }' is not allowed after the closing of '}' of a MarkupExtension expression).

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: did you tried single quotes? `StringFormat=' {0} '`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space in StringFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470410/space-in-stringformat)

Comment: Some detail here: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a100ee6-6206-422b-9b94-11760d325949/how-to-format-text-using-xaml-stringformat?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: @Selvin single quotes is the right answer. Since you answered before Martin place that as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string format needs to be surrounded in quotes:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something, StringFormat=' {0}' }"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set left and right Padding (even if you make it with spaces in StringFormat, their width may vary depending on Font):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something}" Padding="10,0"/>
```

Comment: This answer is definitely more accurate and what I'll be using for my solution, but since the question was specifically about whitespaces in a `StringFormat` and others might have _that_ problem, I'll not be marking it as correct. Still, thank you (not enough points to upvote though, sorry)